# ANTLR4 disambiguation of terminal tokens

Tags: grammar, antlr4

This is my grammar in ANTLR4:

```
grammar Hello;
r  : WORD ID ;
ID : [a-z]+ ;
WORD : [a-z]+ ;      
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

When I type in something like:

```
hello buddy
```

I got the following error message:

```
line 1 missing WORD at 'hello'
```

But, if I change the grammar in

```
grammar Hello;
r  : WORD ID ;
ID : [a-z]+ ;
WORD : [1-9]+ ;      
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

where now WORD is a number, everything is ok.
I strongly suspect that since in the first grammar we have two terminal node with the same regex, the parser doesn't know the correspondance of the real word.
So am I wrong thinking of it? If not, how would you solve this issue keeping more than one terminal with the same regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two terminals that match the same pattern.

If your grammar actually needs to match twice `[a-z]+`, then use a production like

```
r   : WORD WORD ;
```

and the discrimination will be done at the parser / tree traversal level.

If either `WORD` or `ID` can be restricted to a fixed list, you could declare all the possible words as terminals then use them to define e.g. what a `WORD` can be.

Answer (score 0):

> where now WORD is a number, everything is ok.

Not really :

```
$ alias
alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
$ grun Hello r -tokens data.txt 
[@0,0:4='hello',<ID>,1:0]
[@1,6:10='buddy',<ID>,1:6]
[@2,12:11='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
line 1:0 missing WORD at 'hello'
```

When the lexer can match some input with two rules, there is an ambiguity, and it chooses the first rule. With a `hello buddy` input, the lexer produces two ID tokens

- with the first grammar, because it's ambiguous and ID comes first
- with the second grammar, the input can only be matched by ID WS ID

You can disambiguate with a predicate in the lexer rule like so :

```
grammar Question;

/* Ambiguous input */

file
    : HELLO ID
    ;

HELLO
    : [a-z]+ {getText().equals("hello")}? ;
ID  : [a-z]+ ;
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Execution :

```
$ grun Question file -tokens data.txt 
[@0,0:4='hello',<HELLO>,1:0]
[@1,6:10='buddy',<ID>,1:6]
[@2,12:11='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
```

More on semantic predicates in [The Definitive ANTLR Reference](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference).